Kivy and Asyncio... and Thread (How to use async_runTouchApp?)
Am making an App that is structured like this:
-main.py
-first_screen.py
-second_screen.py
-bluetooth.py
-other_files.

In the main.py file i just "create the app" and import the first_screen.py and second_screen.py and some little things.
Now, in first_screen.py i press a button to start a bluetooth connection (pointing from the .kv file to a method in bluetooth.py)
this is bluetooth.py:
import threading
import asyncio
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.event import EventDispatcher
import bleak

device_name = "my_board" # Replaced with actual bluetooth address
SwitchCharacteristic = "beb5483e-36e1-4688-b7f5-ea07361b26a8"

class Bluetooth_board(EventDispatcher):

    status = StringProperty("Conectar")
    client = bleak.BleakClient(device_name)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    
    def run_bleak(self):
        if self.client.is_connected:
            print("You are already connected")
        else:
            threading.Thread(target=self.start_connection).start()
    
    def start_connection(self):
        asyncio.run(self.board())

    def callback(self,sender: bleak.BleakGATTCharacteristic, data: bytearray):
        text = data.decode(encoding="utf-8")
        print(text)

    async def board(self):    
        self.status = "Connecting..."
        devices = await bleak.BleakScanner.discover()
        
        # Filtrar el dispositivo por nombre
        target_device = None
        for device in devices:
            if device.name == device_name:
                target_device = device
                break
        
        if target_device is not None:
            print(f"Device found: {target_device.name} - {target_device.address}")
            self.client = bleak.BleakClient(target_device)

        else: 
            print("Device not found")
            self.status = "Decive not found"
            #End everything
        try:
            await self.client.connect()
            self.status = "Connected"
            print("Waiting data")
            
            while True:
                await self.client.start_notify(SwitchCharacteristic,self.callback)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

        finally:
            await self.client.disconnect()

As you can see, here im using Thread and it is working fine. But, i want to end the thread and the async if the device is not found.
I ask in other forums and they point to me

ey! but why are you using thread and async? just use async! look at
"async_runTouchApp"!

And i look some examples, there is just a few in the internet, and i dont get how to use it in my case.
Because im starting the async method when a button is pressed and not at the beginning, from main.py, like the 3 or 4 examples that you can find in the internet.
Can you give me a hand?
Thanks!
